# How to delete a shortcut if a file does not exists in a Windows .BAT file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

My file `C:\testing\file.exe` is deleted but the shortcut remains on desktop.

How do i delete the shortcut using .bat file ?

It works if i manually delete but i have to write a .bat file with some updates and other users will run the same script in their laptop.

This is the command which i have in my .bat file

```
REM delete the old shotcut lnk file
del "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\fileshortcut.lnk"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the [shortcutjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat).With the `-examine` switch you can list a shortcut properties.If you have shortcut in the same directory use this:

```
@echo off

:: Set the path to the shortcut you want to check
set "shortcut=C:\Shortcut.lnk"

for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('shortcutjs.bat -examine "%shortcut%"^|findstr /b /i "Target"') do (
    set "target=%%B"
)
echo %target%
if not exist "%target%" (
    REM if the command is ok delete the ECHO word bellow
    echo del /q /f "%shortcut%"
)
```